# MySQL Update query too slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I have an update query which takes more than 2 hours to execute. The query updates three tables simultaneously based on some cases . Update query is little complex based on business requirement. How to optimize this query:
Query is as below :

```
UPDATE 
        atmissuerdata a1 
inner join 
        cbsissuerdata c1 ON ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) =ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber) 
INNER JOIN 
        switchissuerdata s1 ON ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) =ROW( s1.approvalnumber,s1.cardnumber) 
INNER JOIN 
        atmlevel1 al1 ON al1.id=a1.id INNER JOIN cbslevel1 cl1 ON cl1.id=c1.id 
INNER JOIN 
        switchlevel1 sl1 ON sl1.id=s1.id 
SET  
        a1.reconstatus = 
                        CASE 
                WHEN (  ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber)   AND
                        ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( s1.approvalnumber,s1.cardnumber) ) AND 
                (  a1.TransactionAmount =   c1.TransactionAmountDr  AND   a1.TransactionAmount =   s1.TransactionAmount1  ) 
                THEN 'Y'   
                WHEN 
                        ( ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber) 
                        AND ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( s1.approvalnumber,s1.cardnumber) ) 
                        AND (  a1.TransactionAmount <>   c1.TransactionAmountDr OR a1.TransactionAmount <>   s1.TransactionAmount1 ) 
                THEN 'D' 
                ELSE 
                        a1.reconstatus END, 
        c1.reconstatus= 
                CASE WHEN (ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber) 
                        AND ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( s1.approvalnumber,s1.cardnumber) ) 
                        AND ( a1.TransactionAmount =   c1.TransactionAmountDr  AND a1.TransactionAmount =  s1.TransactionAmount1 ) 
                THEN 'Y' 
                WHEN (  ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber)   AND
                        ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( s1.approvalnumber,s1.cardnumber) ) AND 
                (  a1.TransactionAmount <>   c1.TransactionAmountDr    OR   a1.TransactionAmount <>   s1.TransactionAmount1  )  
                THEN 'D'   
                ELSE 
                        c1.reconstatus END ,
        s1.reconstatus= 
                CASE WHEN (ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber) 
                AND ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( s1.approvalnumber,s1.cardnumber) ) 
                AND (  a1.TransactionAmount =   c1.TransactionAmountDr  AND a1.TransactionAmount =  s1.TransactionAmount1 ) 
                THEN 'Y'   
                WHEN ( ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber) 
                        AND ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) = ROW( s1.approvalnumber,s1.cardnumber) ) 
                        AND (  a1.TransactionAmount <> c1.TransactionAmountDr  OR a1.TransactionAmount <>   s1.TransactionAmount1 ) 
                THEN 'D'   
                ELSE s1.reconstatus END;
```

Please help me out ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the business logic out of the sql statement.
Do the checks in the code and then just do a "UPDATE atmissuerdata SET reconstats='Y' WHERE id IN (1,2,5,4,...)", "UPDATE atmissuerdata SET reconstats='N' WHERE id IN (1,2,5,4,...)"

Also are you using index correctly? 
In my mind "inner join cbsissuerdata c1 ON ROW( a1.transactionnumber,a1.cardnumber) =ROW( c1.approvalnumber,c1.cardnumber)" is probably slow as hell. Try to use ids on joins and have a index over it.

Comment: I can`t use three update as all status needs to be updated at the same time. we only pick N data if those get updated in one table to Y next time corresponding N data will not be used. So, query will have to use the same one.